# Forwarding variadic template parameter to printf-like function

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have the following log function:

```
template<typename... Arguments>
void Log(const char* file, const int line, int level, const char* fmt, Arguments... args)
{
   std::string formattedFile;

   if (file)
   {
      boost::filesystem::path p(file);
      formattedFile = p.filename().string();
   }

   std::string message{boost::str(boost::format("%1%:%2% [%3%] - %s") % formattedFile % line % m_uxid % fmt)};
   __android_log_print(level, m_tag.c_str(), message.c_str(), args...);
}
```

This application is run on Android using NDK, so this is the logging system for that platform. The problem is that `__android_log_print()` fails to compile with:

```
error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
          __android_log_print(level, m_tag.c_str(), message.c_str(), std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
                                                                                                 ^
```

I'm not sure what this means. Am I not using the variadic template argument correctly?

Comment: Quite plain: You asked your implementation to enforce format-string-correctness by passing `-Werror=formant-security` (maybe using something more inclusive), and it is not able to guarantee that the passed format-string is safe.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to `std::forward` stuff to a C-style variadic function, and even less sense to do it when you are not taking the arguments by universal reference.

Comment: @T.C. I disagree. It makes perfect sense to do so when that C-style function is a variant of `printf`, because you can't easily rewrite `printf` by yourself as a variadic template, and variadic templates are more powerful than C-style variadics (for example, you can forward with an additional argument added at the end, try doing that with a `va_list`). Also it's okay to take the arguments by value because `printf` does.

Comment: @Brian I'm talking about the use of `std::forward` in particular, not the concept of forwarding.

Comment: @T.C. Whoops, my bad. Gotcha.

Comment: `format not a string literal` is exactly what it says on the tin - you need to pass the format as a literal. See `-Wformat-nonliteral` here [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Warning-Options.html)for why that's a problem

Comment: @T.C. What do you mean by "universal reference", I had trouble understanding what `std::forward` actually does, but I found that in a sample online so I used it. Can you explain?

Comment: http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: Thanks @T.C., now that I have read about universal references it doesn't make sense to not use `Arguments&&...`. But if I don't use it, is it taking all of those parameters by value as if I had typed them out by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untrusted input into `printf` can be a security problem. Enforcing the format by using a string literal is one way of improving security

Turning warnings into errors will cause the build to fail so you are forced to address the warning.

GCC's [warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) have this to say

`-Werror`:
Make all warnings into errors.

`-Wformat-security`:
Warn about uses of format functions that represent possible security problems.
At present, this warns about calls to printf and scanf functions where **the format string is not a string literal** and there are **no format arguments**
This may be a security hole if the format string came from untrusted input and contains `%n`.

What is generally advised is to create a `std::string` in your function and pass this with a `%s` format string literal to your logging function

```
__android_log_print(level, m_tag.c_str(), "%s", message.c_str());
```

Where message is built from processing `args...`, typically using something like `boost::format` or a `std::stringstream`.

If you want to use your provided `fmt` string and the variadic args, you can parse the arguments using a custom `printf` style function which produces a `std::string`

```
std::string va_string_printf(const char* format, va_list ap)
{
    char stack_buf[256];

    char* buf = stack_buf;
    int buf_size = sizeof(stack_buf);

    std::string out_str;

    while(true)
    {
        va_list ap1;
        va_copy(ap1, ap);
        int min_buf_size = vsnprintf(buf, buf_size, format, ap1) + 1;
        va_end(ap1);

        if (min_buf_size > buf_size)
        {
            if (buf != stack_buf) // allocate a bigger buffer
                delete[] buf;

            buf = new char[min_buf_size];
            buf_size = min_buf_size;
            continue;
        }

        out_str = buf;
        break;
    }

    if (buf != stack_buf)
        delete[] buf;

    return out_str;
}

std::string string_printf(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    std::string str = va_string_printf(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return str;
}
```